# xstring font change

Tags: xstring

Simple question. I have two macros for displaying abbreviated days of the week such as MWF or TR. I am not sure why the first macro in my MWE fails while the second macro works. I would prefer that something like the first macro works because it is shorter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{suffix}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\textsc*[1]{%
    \textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}%
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Repeat}[2]{%\repeat already used
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{#2}%
}
\usepackage{xstring}
%\newcommand{\weekdays}[1]{%doesn't work
%   \textsc*{%
%       \IfSubStr{#1}{1}{N}{}%Sunday
%       \IfSubStr{#1}{2}{M}{}%Monday
%       \IfSubStr{#1}{3}{T}{}%Tuesday
%       \IfSubStr{#1}{4}{W}{}%Wednesday
%       \IfSubStr{#1}{5}{R}{}%Thursday
%       \IfSubStr{#1}{6}{F}{}%Friday
%       \IfSubStr{#1}{7}{S}{}%Saturday
%   }%
%}
\newcommand{\weekdays}[1]{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{1}{\textsc*{N}}{}%Sunday
    \IfSubStr{#1}{2}{\textsc*{M}}{}%Monday
    \IfSubStr{#1}{3}{\textsc*{T}}{}%Tuesday
    \IfSubStr{#1}{4}{\textsc*{W}}{}%Wednesday
    \IfSubStr{#1}{5}{\textsc*{R}}{}%Thursday
    \IfSubStr{#1}{6}{\textsc*{F}}{}%Friday
    \IfSubStr{#1}{7}{\textsc*{S}}{}%Saturday
}
\begin{document}
\weekdays{246}\quad\weekdays{35}
\Repeat{7}{\par\weekdays{\n}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why complicating things with `\MakeLowercase` when you can just use lowercase in the definition.

Anyway, `xstring` commands aren't expandable and this is the problem you have.

It might be solved with `xstring`, but there's a much better way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Repeat}[2]{%\repeat already used
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{#2}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\textsmallcaps}{m}
 {
  \textsc { \text_lowercase:n { #1 } }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\weekdayinitial}{m}
 {
  \exp_args:Ne \str_map_function:nN { #1 } \egreg_weekday:n
 }

\cs_new:Nn \egreg_weekday:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {1}{N}
    {2}{M}
    {3}{T}
    {4}{W}
    {5}{R}
    {6}{F}
    {7}{S}
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\weekdays}{m}
 {
  \textsmallcaps { \weekdayinitial { #1 } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\weekdays{246}\quad\weekdays{35}

\Repeat{7}{\par\weekdays{\n}}

\end{document}
```

I wouldn't use `suffix`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `\textsc*` `\MakeLowercase` internally does full expansion via `\protected@edef` while `\IfSubStr` is not expandable.
You can use `\unexpanded` for preventing expansion.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{suffix}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\textsc*[1]{%
    \textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}%
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Repeat}[2]{%\repeat already used
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{#2}%
}
\usepackage{xstring}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\weekdays}[1]{%
   \textsc*{%
     \unexpanded{%
       \IfSubStr{#1}{1}{N}{}%Sunday
       \IfSubStr{#1}{2}{M}{}%Monday
       \IfSubStr{#1}{3}{T}{}%Tuesday
       \IfSubStr{#1}{4}{W}{}%Wednesday
       \IfSubStr{#1}{5}{R}{}%Thursday
       \IfSubStr{#1}{6}{F}{}%Friday
       \IfSubStr{#1}{7}{S}{}%Saturday
     }%
   }%
}
\begin{document}
\weekdays{246}\quad\weekdays{35}
\Repeat{7}{\par\weekdays{\n}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This way expanding the argument is delayed until after lowercasing. When lowercasing is done, then `\IfSubStr`-directives are carried out. `\IfSubStr` also fully expands the argument.
But with lowercasing an argument, whose expansion is prevented during lowercasing, passing `\csname..\endcsname`-expressions whose expansion at some stage yields digit sequences may be a problem because lowercasing might change what is between `\csname` and `\endcsname` and thus might change what control sequence token is formed from the `\csname...\endcsname`-expression.

Therefore [the solution of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679854/118714) is to prefer.

---

Alternatively you can use `\noexpand` for preventing expansion of the token `\IfSubStr` only.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{suffix}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\textsc*[1]{%
    \textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}%
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Repeat}[2]{%\repeat already used
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{#2}%
}
\usepackage{xstring}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\weekdays}[1]{%
   \textsc*{%
       \noexpand\IfSubStr{#1}{1}{N}{}%Sunday
       \noexpand\IfSubStr{#1}{2}{M}{}%Monday
       \noexpand\IfSubStr{#1}{3}{T}{}%Tuesday
       \noexpand\IfSubStr{#1}{4}{W}{}%Wednesday
       \noexpand\IfSubStr{#1}{5}{R}{}%Thursday
       \noexpand\IfSubStr{#1}{6}{F}{}%Friday
       \noexpand\IfSubStr{#1}{7}{S}{}%Saturday
   }%
}
\begin{document}
\weekdays{246}\quad\weekdays{35}
\Repeat{7}{\par\weekdays{\n}}
\par
\def\foobar{1357}
\weekdays{\foobar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Still lowercasing the argument is not prevented, which with customized `\lccode`-settings might lead to unexpected results.